# DIAG [S1000] [SAP AG][LIBODBCHDB SO][HDBODBC] General error;-10427 Conversion of parameter/column (8) from data type NVARCHAR to ASCII failed

Tags: php, odbc, hana

I connect to BBDD HANA from PHP code. The connector is unixodbc. (table have spanish characters)

When try to select records, if any field have special characters (ex: euro character) they skip fetch and log in odbc:

DIAG [S1000] [SAP AG][LIBODBCHDB SO][HDBODBC] General error;-10427 Conversion of parameter/column (8) from data type NVARCHAR to ASCII failed

The config odbc.ini

```
[hanadb]
Driver = /usr/sap/hdbclient/libodbcHDB.so
ServerNode = 172.17.xx.xx:31015
```

(i try to add this line, without any change)

```
DriverUnicodeType=1
DriverManagerEncoding = UTF-8
Locale = es_ES
characterset=UTF8
IANAAPPCODEPAGE=2026
```

The code in php

```
$result = odbc_exec($link,"SELECT * FROM ZIF_TCONDW ");

while($datos=odbc_fetch_array($result)) {
    $query=sprintf("INSERT INTO condiciones values
   {...}
```

fields with text:

> Pedidos de 701€ a 1200€

Crash, and in the trace file:

DIAG [S1000] [SAP AG][LIBODBCHDB SO][HDBODBC] General error;-10427 Conversion of parameter/column (8) from data type NVARCHAR to ASCII failed

I try too convert type in select sentence

```
$result = odbc_exec($link,"SELECT LIFNR,ZONA,POSCOND,LEFT(STRTOBIN(CONCEPTO,'UTF-8') ,400) AS CONCEPTO, CONDICION ,ORDEN,AEDAT,AEUHR,AENAM FROM ZIF_TCONDW ");
```

or

```
$result = odbc_exec($link,"SELECT LIFNR,ZONA,POSCOND,base64_encode(CONCEPTO) AS CONCEPTO, base64_encode(CONDICION) AS CONDICION ,ORDEN,AEDAT,AEUHR,AENAM FROM ZIF_TCONDW ");
```

Without change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem that occurs when the ODBC driver tries to hand over Unicode data to your client variables. 
You might want to set the `CHAR_AS_UTF8 = true` connection option to avoid that.
See [SAP HANA Client Interface Programming Reference](https://help.sap.com/viewer/0eec0d68141541d1b07893a39944924e/2.0.02/en-US/7cab593774474f2f8db335710b2f5c50.html).

Comment: I had this same issue, I added CHAR_AS_UTF8 = true to my odbc.ini file and that resolved that output from database was UTF-8 and correct. When I wan't to select something from database with special char I still don't get any result back.
Example: SELECT M.EXTWG FROM SAPHANADB.A923 M WHERE M.KNUMH = '0000918863'
Returns value: BÜRKLE
When I run sql: SELECT M.EXTWG FROM SAPHANADB.TWEW M WHERE M.EXTWG = 'BÜRKLE'
It doesn't return any data.